# Iron Router onBeforeAction triggered by Meteor.loginWithPassword and destroys template?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

All my routes have a typical `onBeforeAction` that requires a login and then forwards the user on to their requested route. It looks like this:

```
if(!Meteor.user()) {
    if(Meteor.loggingIn())
        this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
    else
        this.render('loginPage');           
}
else 
    this.next();
```

The problem is when my login page tries to log in a user using `Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password)` and the login fails. Upon failing, I reveal error messages on my login page. However the `Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password)` actually triggers the `onBeforeAction` to run again.  The `onBeforeAction` reruns and recalls `this.render('loginPage')` and re-renders the `loginPage` and destroys my error message and shows a clean login page again without the error messages - thus confusing the user.

I actually tried to solve this by setting a `Session` variable when the `loginPage` renders, but if I change the `onBeforeAction` to:

```
if(!Meteor.user()) {
    if(Meteor.loggingIn())
        this.render(this.loadingTemplate);
    else {
        if(Session.get('onLoginPage') != true)
           this.render('loginPage');           
    }
}
else 
    this.next();
```

Then the template goes **blank** after `Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password)` gets called and fails.  If the login is valid, there's no problem as the user gets forwarded on to their requested route, but on failure it does this.

Something with Meteor and the `Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password)` method is destroying the template and triggering the `onBeforeAction` again. I am calling it in the `click` event of the sign-in button on the client, but that should be fine.

I know my `loginPage` route works and so does the error handling because if I go directly to the `loginPage` route (which has no `onBeforeAction`, only a default `action`) everything works fine including the error handling.

Using Meteor 1.1.0.3 and Iron Router 1.0.9

Comment: Try putting your loading template in the general configuration with `Router.configure({loadingTemplate: 'loading'})` and avoiding explicitly rendering the loading template during `Meteor.loggingIn()` - that should avoid your login template being reloaded.

Comment: That was it.  I actually had `Router.configure({loadingTemplate: 'loading'})` set correctly, but was also still calling `this.render(this.loadingTemplate)`.  Still a novice at Iron Router.  This is kind of a weird gotcha because when I take out the above, the `onBeforeAction` doesn't even get recalled upon a failed login.  So I assume it's `Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password)` reactively invalidating and recalling `Meteor.loggingIn()` which recalls the entire `onBeforeAction`.

Comment: Glad it worked out for you!